# Connect to RHEL server in virtualbox from outside

Tags: virtualbox, rhel

In RHEL7 server virtualbox, I started a server which I am supposed to check result via http://127.0.0.1:1517/ in the web browser. Since it is a server image I need to check results from the outside of the virtualbox.

From Google search I know that I should go to VirtualBox Settings -> Network and attach this VM to a Bridged Adapter (which I chose the first one "en0: Wi-Fi(AirPort)". However after I set those, this webpage is still unreachable from the outside web browser.

Did I do anything wrong, or there are other configurations need to be set?

---

Summary: It's not a good idea to use VM to build a server that can be accessed by the outside client. Better build a stand alone machine with independent memory and CPU, otherwise there could be serious problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address you provide (http://127.0.0.1:1517/) is your local adress. Don't expect check nothing out of your RHEL server with this address.

To access to your VM from outside you need to change the VirtualBox network settings. As you said, you need to select a Bridged Adapter insted of NAT by default.

**Configure Bridged Adapter in VirtualBox**

First of all shutdown your VM to prevent any conflict between OS and VB Hypervisor. Go to your VM settings and change the network adapter setting as :

- Enable Network Adapter : Check
- Attached to : Bridged Adapter
- Name : Select the card use by your host computer to access to the LAN you want
- Adapter Type : Use default
- Promiscuous Mode : Allow All
- MAC Address : Use default
- Cable connected : Check

Press OK and power your machine.

**Configure VM for Bridged Adapter**

You will also need to configure your virtual network adapter in your RHEL machine. To configure configure your virtual interface you will need :

- Free IP address on your network (IP.address)
- Netmask of your network (netmask)

On command terminal type :

```
ifconfig -a
```

Note the interface's name which belongs to the virtual network adapter you configure before. Then type :

```
sudo ifconfig <interface> <IP.address> netmask <netmask> 
sudo ifdown <interface>
sudo ifup <interface>
```

Now you should be able to access to your machine from outside your VM through the IP address you just provide.